# How to pass parameters to ocl kernel using pyopencl?

Tags: opencl, pyopencl

how to pass some parameters, which will be treated in the .cl file as a preprocessor define using pyopencl?

Meaning:

**foo.cl**

```
# define LIMIT 12
typedef struct {
    uint i[LIMIT];
} foomatic;
```

turns to

**foo_nodefs.cl**

```
typedef struct {
    uint i[LIMIT]; // python script passing LIMIT to set it
} foomatic;
```

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 4):

Edit: extending the answer, making it maximally detailed.

There are two ways to do that:

1. (metaprogramming) Add your preprocessor directives directly to the string with the source code, or even run your own preprocessor using some templating engine.

   ```
   import pyopencl as cl
   import numpy
   import numpy.linalg as la

   a = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)
   b = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)

   ctx = cl.create_some_context()
   queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

   mf = cl.mem_flags
   a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
   b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b)
   dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, b.nbytes)

   defines = """
       #define AXIS 0
       #define COEFF 1
       """

   prg = cl.Program(ctx,
       defines +
       """
       __kernel void sum(__global const float *a,
       __global const float *b, __global float *c)
       {
         int gid = get_global_id(AXIS);
         c[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid] + COEFF;
       }
       """).build()

   prg.sum(queue, a.shape, None, a_buf, b_buf, dest_buf)

   a_plus_b = numpy.empty_like(a)
   cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_plus_b, dest_buf)

   print(la.norm(a_plus_b - (a+b+1)), la.norm(a_plus_b))
   ```
2. (C-way) use `options` keyword of `Program.build` to pass build options directly to [clBuildProgram()](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html):

   ```
   import pyopencl as cl
   import numpy
   import numpy.linalg as la

   a = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)
   b = numpy.random.rand(50000).astype(numpy.float32)

   ctx = cl.create_some_context()
   queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

   mf = cl.mem_flags
   a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
   b_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=b)
   dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, b.nbytes)

   prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
       __kernel void sum(__global const float *a,
       __global const float *b, __global float *c)
       {
         int gid = get_global_id(AXIS);
         c[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid] + COEFF;
       }
       """).build(options=['-D', 'AXIS=0', '-D', 'COEFF=1'])

   prg.sum(queue, a.shape, None, a_buf, b_buf, dest_buf)

   a_plus_b = numpy.empty_like(a)
   cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_plus_b, dest_buf)

   print(la.norm(a_plus_b - (a+b+1)), la.norm(a_plus_b))
   ```

(I have used the modifed source code from the main page of PyOpenCL docs. Tested on pyopencl 2013.1).

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate two strings in Python? Please provide some minimal example for me to work with, because I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: No. I'd like to know, where you want me to place the parameter as a string? Do you mean the string you read in to load the cl source to build it? Meaning cl.Program(ctx, <HERE>).build()

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just modify the string you pass.

Comment: Alright, but isn't there another regular way? I read somewhen somewhere that you can do it by some arguments. What about?

Comment: Yep, there is a way. Added it to the answer (although I personally do not see any reason to pick it over string manipulation).

Comment: Nice, and what if I have more than 1 parameter? Do I write options=['-D', 'LIMIT=12', 'PARAM2=123']?

Comment: ``['-D', 'LIMIT=12', '-D', 'PARAM2=123']``. It works exactly like passing arguments to a command line utility. ``options`` are passed directly to http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html (see the full list of available options there)

Comment: You are wrong. It is

`program = cl.Program(ctx, source).build(options=['-DLIMIT=12','-DPARAM=12'])`

It has to be

**-Dname**

like

**-DLIMIT**. Please, correct your answer.

Comment: Strange, my opencl compiler says, it does not understand "limit=12" when I use `['-D', 'LIMIT=12']`. But using `['-DLIMIT=12']` it works. Maybe its because of the SDK. What GPU do you have? AMD or NVIDIA? I have NVIDIA.

Comment: nVidia gf9600, on OSX 10.8, which may be the problem, since Aplle's OpenCL implementation is known to behave weirdly in other ways. As a matter of fact, this difference speaks in favor of choosing method 1 over method 2.

Comment: Well I have a gf9400 on Linux. I think we both are right, so you should modify your answer adding OSX and Linux case. But I do not know, how Windows behaves, so maybe someone else tries on windows and leaves a comment, so you can modify your answer.